# Elixir, List is not referring to new changes inside Enum.map

Tags: list, dictionary, enums, elixir

I Appended a list in elixir. And try to access its element Enum.map with new index. But I am not able to access the newer element appended to the list. While IO.inspect shows says it is already added but if I inspect inside Enum.map I get the old list.

For the following elixir code:

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
add = [5, 6, 7, 8]
data = list + add

data
|> Enum.with_index(0)
|> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> %{:current => k, :next => list |> Enum.at(v + 1)} end)
|> IO.inspect()
```

> Output

```
[
  %{current: 0, next: 1},
  %{current: 1, next: 2},
  %{current: 2, next: 3},
  %{current: 3, next: 4},
  %{current: 4, next: nil},
  %{current: 5, next: nil},
  %{current: 6, next: nil},
  %{current: 7, next: nil},
  %{current: 8, next: nil}
]
```

> Expected Output

```
[
  %{current: 0, next: 1},
  %{current: 1, next: 2},
  %{current: 2, next: 3},
  %{current: 3, next: 4},
  %{current: 4, next: 5},
  %{current: 5, next: 6},
  %{current: 6, next: 7},
  %{current: 7, next: 8},
  %{current: 8, next: nil}
]
```

**How to get the expected output by my given code and why is this happening?**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that was a silly mistake.

Instead of list I need to type data like this:

> Original

```
|> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> %{:current => k, :next => list |> Enum.at(v + 1)} end)
```

> Correction

```
|> Enum.map(fn {k, v} -> %{:current => k, :next => data |> Enum.at(v + 1)} end)
```